# Как спарсить только часть содержимого строки?

Tags: php, phpquery

День добрый. Учусь парсить страницы и вот, собственно, код который парсит содержимое span.

```
articul = $position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text();
```

Он вытащит текст с первого span. Текст следующий: `Артикул: 02000040`.
Вопрос, как вытащить только `02000040`, без слова "Артикул:" ?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Вот добавлю свой код:

```html
<?php 
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
 echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";

function parser ($url,$start,$end) {

 if ($start < $end) {
 
  $file = file_get_contents($url);
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

   foreach ($doc->find('.product-list') as $position) {

    $position = pq($position);

    $articul = trim($position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text());

    $price = trim($position->find('.actions .price')->html());

    $saveFile = 'database.txt';
    file_put_contents($saveFile, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $articul));
    file_put_contents($saveFile, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $price),FILE_APPEND);

   } 
   echo "<div class=container>";
    echo "<div class=first>";
     echo "<pre>";
     echo $articul;
     echo "</pre>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=second>";
     echo "<pre>";
     echo $price;
     echo "</pre>";
    echo "</div>";
   echo "</div>";;


   $next = $doc->find('.pagination .active')->next()->find('a')->attr('href');
   
  
  if ( !empty($next) ) {
   $start++;
   parser($next, $start, $end);
  }
 } 
}

$url = "https://www.agro-center.com.ua/combines-a/spare-parts-for-grain-harvesters/john-deere-c/?limit=1514";
$start = 0;
$end = 1;
parser($url,$start,$end);

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();

?>
```

Сейчас это имеет, приблизительно, вот такой вот вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант используйте регулярное выражение вида \d+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Можно строку разбить на подстроки при помощи explode()

foreach ($doc->find('.product-list') as $position) {

                $position = pq($position);

                $articul = trim($position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text());
                $art = explode(": ", $articul); //разбиваем строку на подстроки
                articul = $art[2]; //присваиваем переменной номер артикула

                $price = trim($position->find('.actions .price')->html());

                $saveFile = 'database.txt';
                file_put_contents($saveFile, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $articul));
                file_put_contents($saveFile, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $price),FILE_APPEND);

            }   

Если у вас везде есть слово "Артикул: " то его можно просто убрать из строки используя str_replace():

foreach ($doc->find('.product-list') as $position) {

                $position = pq($position);

                $articul = trim($position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text()); 

                $articul = str_replace("Артикул: ", "", $articul);//Убираем "Артикул: " со строки

                $price = trim($position->find('.actions .price')->html());

                $saveFile = 'database.txt';
                file_put_contents($saveFile, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $articul));
                file_put_contents($saveFile, iconv('utf-8','windows-1251', $price),FILE_APPEND);

            }
```

Comment: Я икал в этом направлении.А если в переменную $articul заходит больше 1500 значений, что в таком случае делать? При том, что они все разные.
Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Ну у вас конкретный вопрос "Текст следующий: Артикул: 02000040. Вопрос, как вытащить только 02000040, без слова "Артикул:" ?". Все 1500 значений находятся в одном теге <span>? Я так понимаю вы в цикле будете проходить по всех спанах и парсить с них инфу и на каждом шаге получать артикул.

Comment: так точно. На каждой странице ищет div.name и в нем первый span.

Comment: приведите пример переменной $articul в которую заходит больше 1500 значений

Comment: Я добавил код и скриншот к ответу.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением

Comment: внес правки в ответ

Comment: @ Dmitriy Kondratiuk, Ваше решении тоже, к сожалению,  не помогло.

Comment: я там забыл ")" в конце. Внес правки попробуйте теоретически должно работать.

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, я доставлял ")" вконце, тоже не сработало.
Даже когда просто в echo вывести str_replace("Артикул: ", "", $articul); не хочет работать

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk, заработало. Нужно было между "" поставить пробел. 
Отмечаю как ответ на вопрос! Спасибо большое, Вам!

Answer (score 1):

Можно рассмотреть такой вариант:

```
echo preg_replace('~^Артикул:\s(.+?)$~m', "$1", $articul);
```

Comment: там в самих артикулах есть буквы

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, исправил

Comment: @Let's say Pie, Почему-то не исключает слово Артикул.Хотя я был уверен что зайдет такое решение.

Comment: @SlavaAwaken, исправил, попробуйте этот вариант

Comment: @ Let's say Pie, Не зашло. Скажите, вот в коде после слова Артикул стоит символ пробела &nbsp;, может из-за него не получается?

Comment: @ Let's say Pie имеет вот такой вот вид 
https://ibb.co/mYAveJ

Comment: Попробуйте так: `echo preg_replace('~Артикул:&nbsp;(.+)$~m', "$1", $articul);`

Comment: @ Let's say Pie, нет, никак не хочет. У меня уже голова кругом.

Comment: Выложите часть самого кода который приходит вам.

Comment: @ Let's say Pie, то есть часть кода, который парсит этот span?

Comment: Вот этого `echo $articul;`

Comment: @Let's say Pie, так я к вопросу код прикреплял и то, что он выводит в браузер